# UnsupportedOperationException: CteInsertStrategy can only be used with Dialects that support CTE that can take UPDATE or DELETE statements as well

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, ddl

I would like to generate ddl using my entities.
Please note I'm using latest springboot 3.0.6

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>accessing-data-jpa-complete</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here it is the entity class, it's a small entity for testing purpose.

```
package com.example.accessingdatajpa.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    protected Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']", id, firstName, lastName);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

application.yml :

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: admin
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: postgres
    type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
    driver-class-name: 
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp: 
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults property: false
      javax:
          schema-generation:
            scripts:
              action: create
              create-source: metadata
              create-target: create.sql
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
```

I tried to execute mvn clean install which is supposed to trigger ddl generation.Unfortunately create.sql is not generated and get the following stack :

```
Suppressed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CteInsertStrategy can only be used with Dialects that support CTE that can take UPDATE or DELETE statements as well
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.cte.CteInsertStrategy.<init>(CteInsertStrategy.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.cte.CteInsertStrategy.<init>(CteInsertStrategy.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.getFallbackSqmInsertStrategy(PostgreSQLDialect.java:828) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.mutation.internal.SqmMutationStrategyHelper.resolveInsertStrategy(SqmMutationStrategyHelper.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.interpretSqmMultiTableInsertStrategy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5987) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.lambda$prepareMappingModel$12(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5840) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess$PostInitCallbackEntry.process(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.MappingModelCreationProcess.executePostInitCallbacks(MappingModelCreationProcess.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
        ... 102 common frames omitted
```